# What is the easiest way to assign each individual result from a MySQL query into a unique array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, unique

Basically I want to call these variables at other places in the document, but I am not sure what the easiest way to do this would be. For example in my specific case, my query is this:

```
     $query = "SELECT report,";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT analyst) AS analysts, ";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT region) AS regions, ";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country) AS countries, ";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT topic) AS topics, ";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT date) AS dates, ";
        $query.= "GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT province) AS provinces ";
        $query.= "FROM reports GROUP BY report ORDER BY docID DESC ";

      $result = mysql_query($query);

  while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { yada yada yada }
```

I would like to have each individual $row save as a unique array where I can call it someplace else in the document, in my case, I am trying to call them as default values for some form inputs. I can think of several ways to do this, but they all look quite involved, adding some nested for statements, and incrementing i...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

how about

```
$data = array()
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Which gives you a parent `$data` array, where each element in it is one of the associative arrays you fetched.

Answer (score 2):

Each $row will be unique, contents-wise, assuming each resulting database row is unique. Stick the rows into an array called $rows like so -

```
$rows = array();
$result = mysql_query($query);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $row;
  ...
}
```

If you're talking about naming each row as a unique variable, there are things you could do, but then you're left with unpredictable variable names to try and figure out, so I'm hoping that's NOT what you mean :)